# Observable looses value after display , ionic app and angular fire to fetch values from firestore

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, rxjs, google-cloud-firestore

This is the behaviour which is causing the problem. https://media.giphy.com/media/1o1oEgsCSoV9wYcTx2/source.mp4
When I navigate back from the segment back the values disappear.

The value comes for the first time but then it does not stay. 
I also see that sometimes the observable takes a lot of time to display or fetch values too.

This is my ts file

```
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';

import { SettingsPage } from './../settings/settings';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { Component, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, ModalController, AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection, AngularFirestoreDocument } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import { FirestoreService } from './../../services/firestore.service';

/**
 * Generated class for the ProfileMasterPage page.
 *
 * See https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
 * Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-profile-master',
  templateUrl: 'profile-master.html'
})
export class ProfileMasterPage {
  myuid;
  userRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<any> ;
  details: string = "Info";
  phoneNumbers: Observable<any[]>;
  email: Observable<any[]>;
  web: Observable<any[]>;
  address: Observable<any[]>;
  mypr: Observable<any>;


  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public alertCtrl: AlertController, public modalCtrl: ModalController, public translateService: TranslateService, private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private fs: FirestoreService) {

   this.myuid = this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(result => {this.myuid = result.uid});
   this.translateService.get('DELETE_BUTTON');
}

  ngOnInit(){

    this.userRef = this.fs.doc(`users/${this.myuid}`);
   console.log('userRef', this.userRef);

    //this.mypr = userRef.valueChanges();
     this.mypr = this.fs.doc$(this.userRef);


    this.phoneNumbers = this.fs.colWithIds$(this.userRef.collection('phoneNumbers'));

    this.email = this.fs.colWithIds$(this.userRef.collection('email'));

    this.web = this.fs.colWithIds$(this.userRef.collection('website'));

    this.address = this.fs.colWithIds$(this.userRef.collection('address'));
  }
```

And the firestore service returns this info

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore, 
  AngularFirestoreCollection, 
  AngularFirestoreDocument 
} from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/take';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';

import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

type CollectionPredicate<T>   = string |  AngularFirestoreCollection<T>;
type DocPredicate<T>          = string |  AngularFirestoreDocument<T>;

@Injectable()
export class FirestoreService {


  constructor(public afs: AngularFirestore) { }

  /// **************
  /// Get a Reference
  /// **************

  col<T>(ref: CollectionPredicate<T>, queryFn?): AngularFirestoreCollection<T> {
    return typeof ref === 'string' ? this.afs.collection<T>(ref, queryFn) : ref
  }

  doc<T>(ref: DocPredicate<T>): AngularFirestoreDocument<T> {
    return typeof ref === 'string' ? this.afs.doc<T>(ref) : ref
  }



  /// **************
  /// Get Data
  /// **************


  doc$<T>(ref:  DocPredicate<T>): Observable<T> {
    return this.doc(ref).snapshotChanges().map(doc => {
      return doc.payload.data() as T
    })
  }

  col$<T>(ref: CollectionPredicate<T>, queryFn?): Observable<T[]> {
    return this.col(ref, queryFn).snapshotChanges().map(docs => {
      return docs.map(a => a.payload.doc.data()) as T[]
    });
  }



  /// with Ids
  colWithIds$<T>(ref: CollectionPredicate<T>, queryFn?): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.col(ref, queryFn).snapshotChanges().map(actions => {
      return actions.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data();
        const id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return { id, ...data };
      });
    });
  }
```

And finally my html looks like this

```
<ion-content>
    <div>
        <ion-card>
            <ion-img width="75" height="75" src="./../../assets/img/nin-live.png "></ion-img>
            <ion-card-content>
                <button ion-button icon-left (click)="mainEdit()">
          <ion-icon name="person"></ion-icon>
        </button>
                <ion-card-title>
                    {{ (mypr | async)?.displayName }}
                </ion-card-title>
                <h2>
                    {{ (mypr | async)?.title }}
                </h2>
                <p padding>
                    {{ (mypr | async)?.company }}
                </p>
                <ion-item>{{ (mypr | async)?.city }} </ion-item>
                <ion-item>{{ (mypr | async)?.country }} </ion-item>
            </ion-card-content>


        </ion-card>

        <ion-segment [(ngModel)]="details">
            <ion-segment-button value="Info">
                Card
            </ion-segment-button>
            <ion-segment-button value="Details">
                Details
            </ion-segment-button>
        </ion-segment>

        <div [ngSwitch]="details">

            <ion-list *ngSwitchCase="'Info'">

                <ion-item>
                    <ion-icon name="call" item-start></ion-icon>
                    {{ (mypr | async)?.phnumber }}
                </ion-item>
                <ion-item>
                    <ion-icon name="mail" item-start></ion-icon>
                    {{ (mypr | async)?.email }}
                </ion-item>
                <ion-item>
                    <ion-icon name="link" item-start></ion-icon>
                    {{ (mypr | async)?.website }}
                </ion-item>

            </ion-list>
            <ion-list *ngSwitchCase="'Details'">
                <ion-list-header>
                    Phone Numbers
                </ion-list-header>
                <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let ph of phoneNumbers | async ">
                    <button ion-item (click)="upsert(ph,'phoneNumber')">
                <ion-col>
                    <h3>{{ ph.type }}:</h3>
                   </ion-col>
              <ion-col>
             <p>{{ ph.phNumber  }}</p>
             </ion-col>
            </button>
                    <ion-item-options>
                        <button ion-button color="danger" (click)="delete( ph, 'phoneNumber')">
                {{ 'DELETE_BUTTON' | translate }}
              </button>
                    </ion-item-options>
                </ion-item-sliding>
                <ion-item>
                    <ion-icon name="add" item-start></ion-icon>
                    <button ion-button color="primary" (click)="upsert(ph=null, 'phoneNumber')">
                  add More..
                </button>
                </ion-item>
```

And editing my html to use only 2 async pipe

```
<ion-icon name="person"></ion-icon>
        </button>
                <div *ngIf="mypr | async as user">
                    <ion-card-title>
                        {{ user.displayName }}
                    </ion-card-title>
                    <h2>
                        {{ user.title }}
                    </h2>
                    <p padding>
                        {{ user.company }}
                    </p>
                    <ion-item>{{ user.city }} </ion-item>
                    <ion-item>{{ user.country }} </ion-item>
                </div>
            </ion-card-content>
        </ion-card>

        <ion-segment [(ngModel)]="details">
            <ion-segment-button value="Info">
                Card
            </ion-segment-button>
            <ion-segment-button value="Details">
                Details
            </ion-segment-button>
        </ion-segment>

        <div [ngSwitch]="details">

            <ion-list *ngSwitchCase="'Info'">
                <div *ngIf="mypr | async as user">
                    <ion-item>
                        <ion-icon name="call" item-start></ion-icon>
                        {{ user.phnumber }}
                    </ion-item>
                    <ion-item>
                        <ion-icon name="mail" item-start></ion-icon>
                        {{ user.email }}
                    </ion-item>
                    <ion-item>
                        <ion-icon name="link" item-start></ion-icon>
                        {{ user.website }}
                    </ion-item>
                </div>
            </ion-list>
```

Comment: what's the code for this.fs.docWithRefs$? also, why are you using the async pipe 5 times rather than just once?

Comment: could you change the `ngOnInit` into `ngOnChanges` and test it again?

Comment: @BorisLobanov , I have made the change to the code it should not have been docWithRef but doc$ . However, it is still not working. I also made changes to the async pipe to the code. But still not solving the issue

Comment: @kucing_terbang, no ngOnChanges does not display any data and it is not working

Comment: I never said it would fix it, it just reduces the number of http-calls from 8 to 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving your async pipe outside of the tabs like so:

```
<!-- this should wrap the whole template -->
<ng-container  *ngIf="mypr | async as user">

<!-- some other code of the app -->
<ion-icon name="person"></ion-icon>
    </button>
            <div>
                <ion-card-title>
                    {{ user.displayName }}
                </ion-card-title>
                <h2>
                    {{ user.title }}
                </h2>
                <p padding>
                    {{ user.company }}
                </p>
                <ion-item>{{ user.city }} </ion-item>
                <ion-item>{{ user.country }} </ion-item>
            </div>
        </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>

    <ion-segment [(ngModel)]="details">
        <ion-segment-button value="Info">
            Card
        </ion-segment-button>
        <ion-segment-button value="Details">
            Details
        </ion-segment-button>
    </ion-segment>

    <div [ngSwitch]="details">

        <ion-list *ngSwitchCase="'Info'">
            <div>
                <ion-item>
                    <ion-icon name="call" item-start></ion-icon>
                    {{ user.phnumber }}
                </ion-item>
                <ion-item>
                    <ion-icon name="mail" item-start></ion-icon>
                    {{ user.email }}
                </ion-item>
                <ion-item>
                    <ion-icon name="link" item-start></ion-icon>
                    {{ user.website }}
                </ion-item>
            </div>
        </ion-list>

</ng-container>
```

Comment: Sweet, glad to help! Would you consider upvoting as well? Thanks in advance!

Comment: yeah i did upvote, but since my reputation is less it is not considering :)

Comment: oh thanks :) I upvoted the question as well, hope it helps with your rating